# ng-disabled is not working in chrome .Button is not disabling in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, form-submit

My requirement are:

1. Submit button should be disable before validate all fields.
2. Once the all fields validated,Submit button should be enable to click by users.
3. Once the user click on the button,again Submit button should be disabled.

I used below code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" data-ng-disabled="signup.$invalid" ng-disabled="isDisabled" data-ng-click="saveNewUser()">Submit</button>
```

and in controller I have used

```
$scope.saveNewUser = function () 
                    $scope.isDisabled = true;
```

if any field not validated and error out

```
 if(genderError || stateError || dobError)
                    $scope.isDisabled = false;
```

Above case is working fine in IE and Firefox but it is not working in Chrome.
I have opened the form in Chrome ,button is not showing disabled while it is showing disabled in IE and Firefox even Form is not submitted yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle or working example with your unresponsive code?

Comment: Also, you should not reference two `ng-disabled` attributes, like what you're currently doing `data-ng-disabled="signup.$invalid" ng-disabled="isDisabled"`. Instead, just do `ng-disabled="signup.$invalid || isDisabled"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setup a basic example using Codepen and have it working in Firefox, Safari and Chrome on Mac.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  var genderError = false;
  var stateError = false;
  var dobError = false;

  $scope.saveNewUser = function () {
    $scope.isDisabled = true;

    if(genderError || stateError || dobError) {
      $scope.isDisabled = false; 
    }
  }
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="signup">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="signup.$invalid || isDisabled" ng-click="saveNewUser()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I believe your error was most probably referencing both `data-ng-disabled` and `ng-disabled` on your button. Browsers could interpret this in different ways. Instead, I merged them together on the button to be a single attribute as `ng-disabled="signup.$invalid || isDisabled"`.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/NNVdLr)**